# Prove that $P_nTP_nh \longrightarrow Th$ as $n \to \infty.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, projection

> Let $\{e_n \}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\text {span}\ \{e_1,e_2, \cdots , e_n \},\ n \geq 1.$ Prove that for all bounded linear operator $T : \mathcal H \longrightarrow \mathcal H$ and $h \in H,$ $P_nTP_nh \longrightarrow Th$ as $n \to \infty.$

We can write $h = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left \langle h, e_n \right \rangle e_n.$ Then $P_nTP_n h = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left \langle h, e_k \right \rangle P_n T e_k.$ Since $M = \text {span} \{e_1,e_2, \cdots , e_n \}$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$ of dimension $\geq 1$ it follows that $M$ is a non-zero closed subspace of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and hence $\|P_n\|_{\text {op}} = 1$ (because $P_n$ is a projection onto $M$). Now my idea is to to show $\|P_nTP_nh - Th\|  \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

But how do I do that? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{nrm}[1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}$\begin{align}\nrm{P_nTP_nh-Th}&=\nrm{P_nTP_nh-P_nTh+P_nTh-Th}\le\\&\le \nrm{P_nT(P_nh-h)}+\nrm{P_nTh-Th}\le\\&\le \nrm{P_n}\nrm T\nrm{P_nh-h}+\nrm{P_nTh-Th}\le\\&\le \nrm T\nrm{P_nh-h}+\nrm{P_nTh-Th}\to0\end{align}

Comment: @Anacardium With an irresponsive T key.

Comment: Editing is not good.

Comment: Seems great to me. @Anacardium

Comment: How do I prove that $P_n h \to h$ for any $h \in H\ $?

Comment: Isn't that obvious? That is what $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \langle h,e_k\rangle e_k=h$ means.

Comment: But how do I show that $$\left \|\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \left \langle h,ek \right \rangle e_k \right \| \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$ in a sequential argument? Can it be shown that $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \left \lvert \left \langle h,e_k \right \rangle \right \rvert \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty\ $? For that I need the convergence of the series $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left \lvert \left \langle h,e_k \right \rangle \right \rvert.$$ Right?

Comment: @Anacardium It's Parseval/Bessel.